# Unit tests for printing in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, testing

I have some code that uses the Swing/AWT printing functionality that I want to unit test. It uses the systems native print dialog, but is there any way to get the JVM to intercept that and replace it with a mock during unit testing so that I can get a copy of the image that would be printed?

My code for printing is straightforward and looks roughly like this:

```
     Printable printable = getPrintable();

     PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     printJob.setPrintable(printable);

     if (printJob.printDialog())
     {
        try
        {
           printJob.print();
        }
        catch (PrinterException exception)
        {
           ...
        }
     }
```

I've been using FEST for my other GUI tests but it does not seem to have any support for printing tests. Is this even possible to do, or will I need to write up testing documentation that involves telling QA to go check their printer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my print library: http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/print/

You can create a StandardPrint and generate images for each page that will be rendered

Comment: +1 interesting, (can pretty to ignore) time to moving your goldeggs to Java6

Comment: I'll have to see if I can get away with using your preview method. I'm *supposed* to be doing a full integration test, but this seems to be the best available technical solution to my process problem.